# Excel only replace some entries from csv with python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet which looks like this:

| Pool | Storage | Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20TB | 10TB |
| 2 | 20TB | 10TB |
| 3 | 20TB | 10TB |

I also have the corresponding csv for that. I need to update the values. But not every value in the table is in the csv so just overwriting is not possible. For example Pool 2 might not be in the csv. I can use the name of the pool as identifier.

I want to use python since I do other things in a script already.

Edit:
Currently I use pandas.
dfcsv = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")

With other changes I could just dump the whole content of the csv:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, 
mode="a",if_sheet_exists="overlay",datetime_format="dd.mm.yyyy 
hh:mm") as writer:
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Compute", startcol=0, startrow=3, 
  index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: So, do you have code to read the Excel file?  Do you know how to read a CSV file line by line?  What code have you already tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.